# Security group not properly set when calling RDS CreateDBInstance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to set the security group while creating an RDS instance, using the AWS RDS API. The RDS instance is created, but the security group is not properly set.

The call is:

```
$rds_client->CreateDBInstance(
    'DBSecurityGroups.DBSecurityGroupName.N' => ['office_sg'],
    ....
    ];
```

But when the RDS instance is created, it's assigned the default security group, and I am not getting any error messages as part of the result. It returns the following as part of the call return:

```
[DBInstance] => Array
    (
        [DBInstanceIdentifier] => officesupplies
        [DBInstanceClass] => db.t3.large
        [Engine] => mysql
        [DBInstanceStatus] => creating
        [MasterUsername] => officemaster
        [DBName] => officesupplies
        .....
        [DBSecurityGroups] => Array
            (
            )
```

When I look in the AWS dashboard for the security group, here's what I get:

```
name         security group id     security group name   vpc id
office_sg    sg-0787940c2b64n      office_sg             vpcbb2c7b1n5
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you get your error?

Comment: It did not go. The proper VPN security group is not set. I am using the PHP SDK and I am not calling it exactly like the API docs state. There are no errors generated.

Answer (score 2):

`DBSecurityGroups` is for old-type RDS outside of VPC. These days you **should use** [VpcSecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-vpcsecuritygroups) to set your security groups for RDS instance. You have to check what is the right parameter name for your programming language's SDK. Its not specified what you are programming in.

Comment: I tried 'VpcSecurityGroupIds.VpcSecurityGroupId.N' => ['office_sg'], but same result

Comment: @EastsideDev Could be your code. Please provide full version of it or at least specify what SDK are you using.

Comment: I am using AWS SDK version 3.188.1. The code is executing fine, as the instance is created and I can see it in the dashboard, the only thing that's not right is the vpn security group. I tried the actual id  'VpcSecurityGroupIds.VpcSecurityGroupId.N' => ['sg-xxxxx'] and 'VpcSecurityGroupIds.VpcSecurityGroupId.N' => ['xxxxx'] with no success either

Comment: @EastsideDev Please check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-docdb-2014-10-31.html#createdbinstance) how to use the sdk. They write it should be: `'VpcSecurityGroupIds' => ['<string>', ...]`

Comment: That's in the result, not the call itself. I am doing exactly what the SDK docs say and the parameter is:  VpcSecurityGroupIds.VpcSecurityGroupId.N https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html

Comment: @EastsideDev You are using PHP SDK, not AWS API directly. You must check what PHP docs say, not AWS API docs, unless you craft all the requests yourself without any SDK.